# Ошибка получения данных из БД

Tags: php, laravel

Функционал редактирования пользователя:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $roles = Role::lists('display_name','id');
    $userRole = $user->roles->lists('id','id')->toArray();

    return view('users.edit',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
}
```

Модель `User`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Путь:

```
Route::resource('users','UserController');
```

При попытке отредактировать:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()
```

`.env` файл:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lists` был переименовал в `pluck`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0